# Woocommerce Role based Product Pictures

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, roles

I'm developing a woocommerce website and would appreciate some help regarding an issue I am facing.

I have already set up 2 new user roles (Silver, Gold) and adjust the prices accordingly. So far so good.

What I want now is the ability of showing some of the product images only for those 2 new roles I've added. Not to the default customers.

Is this somehow possible? I've searched for a plugin that could do the job but couldn't find one. I also tried building the below custom function but could not find out how to distinct showing/hidden images.

```
function img_by_user_role {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array('silver', 'gold');
<?php if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {  ?> 
   //stuff here for allowed roles
<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you for your time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'mrhossen' suggested I was able to solve the problem using ACF plugin.

For anyone who may face the same problem, this is how I managed to do so.

1. Created a field Group named "Custom_Gallery"
2. Populate the fields as shown in the screenshot
3. Selected "product" as location
4. On the product page I uploaded my custom field image
5. I used the below snippet in my child-theme single-product.php template where I wanted the Image to show

[Screenshot - ACF Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W7Wu.jpg)

```
<?php if( current_user_can('silver') || current_user_can('gold') ) {  

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; } ?>
```

Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking about **Woocomerce product default gallery**, that 2 extra images will show only for Silver & Gold user.

I don't think it's possible to modify default gallery like this way OR if it's possible that will be complex.

Here have another solution:

1. Hide/Remove **Woocomerce product default gallery**
2. Build New gallery with [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin
3. When you pass the data on frontend just make User Based condition.

That's it. this will save your time & solve your problem very easily.

If need any help on ACF ask me :)

Comment: Hello friend,Thank you for your kind answer. Didn't know about ACF plugin. I will give it a try and post feedback when available. Thanks again for the workaround!

Comment: OK.. try it.. if you don't understand i will give you a quick guideline about how to do.. :)